# How to word wrap the Data Labels in a Pie chart?

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008

I am developing an RDL with a pie chart in SSRS 2008 and I show the Data Labels outside this chart.  However, because my expression is so long, it is being cutoff currently because all of it has to appear on one line for each group.  Is there a way to make it wrap to the next line to prevent this?

Comment: Screenshot could def help here, because I think I know what you're asking, but not totally sure.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a fudge but you can make an expression for the data label and split up and re-concatenate the sentences.  In your base data you might need a column for line 1, line 2, line 3 etc. then in the expression

`=Fields!Line1.Value & CHR(10) & Fields!Line2.Value & CHR(10) & Fields!Line3.Value`

The CHR(10) will put a carriage return in and put the next bit in a new line in the label.

Alternatively split by length of the string into two (or use substrings if you want to split into more).  Of course you might start chopping words in half.  It depends on your audience how important this is to you.  The above way is neater visually.

```
=left(Fields!ShortDescription.Value,round(len(Fields!ShortDescription.Value)/2,0)) & CHR(10) & right(Fields!ShortDescription.Value,round(len(Fields!ShortDescription.Value)/2,0))
```